# Post in R Plumber keeps giving error message

Tags: r, post, plumber

I'm trying to post some values to plumber (0.4.6) API, but I keep getting the following error:

**Error**

```
<simpleError in (function (orgName, reportType, teamCode) {    code <- teamCode    org <- orgName})(): argument "teamCode" is missing, with no default>
```

**Plumber API route**

```
#* @apiTitle Set team codes
#* @post /report
function(orgName, reportType, teamCode){
  
  code <- teamCode
  org <- orgName
  
}
```

**Fiddler showing data sent during POST**

[image]

I tried a few other things based on the documentation and SO questions, but those didn't work either. So, I'm not sure what's happening and why it's not processing the request. I don't understand what the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also had issues like this with `express.js`. I don't know how you're sending the data since you didn't show it. But it seems like the way you're sending the post request may not have the data appropriately formatted - especially since @BrunoTremblay was able to use `httr` to post request. At the minimum, your `express.js` post request should have headers, url, and form.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    url: 'http://localhost:7667/report',
    form: req.body
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return
    }
```

I haven't tested it, but hopefully this will give you an idea to see if your request is also configured the same way.